Spring Boot omits part of Exception Stacktrace from Kafka Listener
Our @KafkaListener annotated method throws an NPE in its consume() method, but the logs omit the stacktrace of the java.lang.NullPointerException. I do not understand why this is the case.
Testing locally by manually throwing an NPE in the method's body I get a proper stacktrace. The logging configuration (included below) has nothing special in it.
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleRemaining(DefaultErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2924)
[...]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void de.suedleasing.slc.posteingang.benutzer.BenutzerListener.consume(de.suedleasing.slc.posteingang.benutzer.BenutzerChangeEvent,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Long,org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)' threw exception
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2957)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2902)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2866)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$55(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2783)
    ... 10 more
    Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:391)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2888)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

For comparison, locally I get a proper stacktrace for the NullPointerException:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at de.suedleasing.slc.posteingang.benutzer.BenutzerListener.consume(BenutzerListener.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:376)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2888)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Logging config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="co/elastic/logging/logback/boot/ecs-console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ECS_JSON_CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>


Different JDK versions?

I think new JDK versions added the ability to specify the variable that was null in an NPE, but here the whole stacktrace is missing which I'm not sure should happen by JDK version differences. Also we're on Java 21 so they can't be too far apart.
